# Concatenating namespace and class name using C preprocessor ## (double hash)

Tags: c++, preprocessor

Can I concatenate a namespace with a class name using the `##` preprocessor directive?

I have written this example to show what I want to do:

```
namespace ns {
class A
{
public:
    void print(){ std::cout << "A" << std::endl; };
};   
}

#define PRINT_NS(E) ([](){ ::ns::##E e; e.print(); }())

int main()
{
  PRINT_NS(A);
}
```

It gives the following compilation error:

```
13:30: error: pasting "::" and "A" does not give a valid preprocessing token
17:3: note: in expansion of macro 'PRINT_NS'
```

It looks like whatever is before the `::` is not considered by `##`.

Comment: Why are you trying to concatenate with `##`? If you don't do that, and instead just do `::ns::E` [it works just fine](http://ideone.com/2uzmrP).

Comment: I was trying to use `##` in a code generator to always add prefixes in the same way no matter whether they are namespaces or parts of the class name, function name etc

Comment: @Martin In this case, your code generator must check whether the prefix ends with `::` and has to generate the appropriate code. I guess this is finally the easier solution than trying to handle this with macros in C++. Is this an option for you to change the code generator?

Comment: I try to recall how I solved this problem in the code generators I wrote: Either the code generator itself concatenated (given) prefix and (generated) symbol or I had separate options for namespaces and prefixes (or supported namespace only because with namespaces _I_ don't need prefixes.) In the first case, it worked with scopes (e.g. `RF::Script::Parser::` as well as simple prefixes (e.g. `rfScriptParser`) but the code generation had general limitations. When I started to generate complete classes (with header and C++ sources) I switched to the latter method.

Comment: Yes, I can work around it outside of the macro. It will impact a few places and i wanted to come up with something neat in the one macro this involves.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no need to glue anything, since `::` is not a preprocessor token preprocessor will be able to substitute E just fine ([working example](http://ideone.com/GRsB0c)):

```
#define PRINT_NS(E) ([](){ ::ns::E e; e.print(); }())
```

`##` should be used when you want to glue parts that otherwise will be treated as a single token, something like this:

```
#define PRINT_NS(E) ([](){ ::ns::My_##E e; e.print(); }())
```